# Centering 2 Divs in a wrapper CSS IE trouble

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to place two divs on the same line (preferably centered) inside a wrapper div. The code I have written works great in FF and IE10. Almost every version of IE <10 doesn't like it. Can anybody help, thanks!

html:

```
<div id="home_wrapper">
    <div id="links_location" class="shadow">content</div>
    <div id="iframe_location" class="shadow">content</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#home_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
}
#links_location, #iframe_location {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:White;
    !important
}
#links_location {
    width:20%;
    height:400px;
    text-align:left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#iframe_location {
    height:400px;
    width:70%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

jsfiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shennessy11/UZGwJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
#links_location, #iframe_location
{
    background-color:White;
    float: left;
 }
```

Is it what you wanted? [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERcAQ/5/)

****Update****

Everything works fine for me in all IE versions if you place `!important` after `white`, like this `background-color: White !important;`. You screw up your css by placing it after semicolon :)

Comment: I thought it was causing an error but not 100% that was it. great, thanks!